# How do I extract an icon class name and its content value from a css file using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have a CSS file for my custom icons, and I want to extract class name and content value from them.

The CSS file has mostly lines like these:

```
.my-icon-bus:before { content: '\e820'; } /* '' */
.my-icon-tools:before { content: '\e821'; } /* '' */
.my-icon-science:before { content: '\e822'; } /* '' */
.my-icon-quotes:before { content: '\e823'; } /* '' */
.my-icon-printer:before { content: '\e827'; } /* '' */
```

I tried the regex pattern below in regex101.com and it works fine - see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/pQ5bN9/1), returning the class name and its content code, but when I try to do the same from PHP using preg_match_all, it doesn't match anything.

```
\.(my-icon-\w+):before\s*{\s*content:\s*(["']\\\w+["']);
```

Here's my PHP code, hopefully one of you RegEx gurus out there can help me figure this out.

```
$css = file_get_contents( '/path/to/my/css/file/my-icon.css' );

preg_match_all( '/\.(my-icon-\w+):before\s*{\s*content:\s*(["\']\\\w+["\']);/s', $css, $matches );
var_dump($matches);
```

In case anyone wonders, the variable $css does have the CSS file contents.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\\.(my-icon-\\w+):before\\s*{\\s*content:\\s*([\"']\\\\\\w+[\"']);/s
```

Notice beginning of string `/\\.`
 (double backslash) and it works fine.

Comment: Actually it didn't work but it pointed me in the right direction - which means after some backslash adding and removing I finally got it to work, it ended up like this: /\.(my-icon-[-\w]+):before\s*{\s*content:\s*(["']\\\\\w+["']);/s - for some reason I had to use five backslashes for the content code... thanks, GR Vitally

Comment: Actually, there is code generator at  regex101.com, and if it works there it should work at your side. I pointed out all that at the beginning double slash, as you can see from snippet, there are much more backslashes...